# Granting roles in bulk

Tags: java, list, arraylist, discord, discord-jda

I am trying to grant everyone on the server who did not verify the Unverified role, bot for some reason when running the command, i get an output as if it works ( Member unverified: *member* )
But they don't actually get the role. I've been scratching my head to this, and can't figure out why.
I am guessing that Discord has some sort of limitation for this, if so lmk :)

```
public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
    //Grants the unverified role, in case someone joined when bot was offline
    if(event.getInteraction().getName().equals("unverify") &&   event.getMember().hasAccess(event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1037390590163288064"))){
        Guild guild = event.getGuild();
        Role unverified = guild.getRoleById("1034143551568752682");
        Role verified = guild.getRoleById("1044611309578236005");

        List<Member> allMembers = guild.getMembers();
        List<Member> unverifiedMembers = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i =0; i < allMembers.size(); i++){
            Member member = allMembers.get(i);
            if(!member.getRoles().contains(verified)){
                unverifiedMembers.add(member);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(unverifiedMembers);
        for (Member unverifiedMember : unverifiedMembers) {
            guild.addRoleToMember(unverifiedMember, unverified).queue();
            System.out.println("Member unverified: " + unverifiedMember);
        }

    }
}
```

I tried delaying granting the role. Did not work. I have no other ideas.

Edit:

Just for info, the server has over 600 members that i need to add the role to, so the output is huge, and is instant
( guessing its too much for discord to handle, but how to get around it? )

Comment: guild.getMembers returns only cached members. Do you have chunking filter set and do you cache members?

Comment: Yes, all is set